# How to download the whole NPM repository for full offline development joy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, offline

Recently I was on holiday with limited internet connectivity. I was developing an application in node.js when I suddenly needed some NPM packages. This put a severe halt in the development and I was forced to wait until I could go online to download said packages and continue development.

Is it possible to mirror the whole npm registry locally on my computer? How to do that?

It should be possible seeing as online mirrors of the main registry exists. Where do they gather all packages from?

Comment: This should help you: https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp#replicating-the-registry.

Comment: See http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/how-to-create-a-private-npmjs-repository

Answer (score 2):

This is what [`npm-offline`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-offline) could do for you.  [`npm-offline`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-offline) could cache modules, you would just need to create a script that ensures you have the modules that you want cached.

Comment: `npm-offline`?  this answer is 5 years old and `npm-offline` is still on version 0.0.1 . I would suggest [verdaciio](https://verdaccio.org/) or [local-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-npm)